# evaluate a proc object in different context

Tags: ruby

Below I create a proc object in the console:

```
2.1.2 :050 > p = Proc.new { where(id: 1)}
```

No error is thrown because the proc object is not evaluated. It just simply stores the chunk of code.

Now I want to evaluate that chunk of code in the context of a Practice ActiveRecord object. I try the following:

```
2.1.2 :051 > Practice.instance_eval { p.call } 
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for main:Object
```

Why I am getting undefined method where for main:Object. This should be evaluated in the context of Practice, not main:Object.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the Proc as an argument so it's executed in that context.

```
Practice.instance_eval(&p)
```

Comment: Yes that works too, but I don't fully see why my initial way didn't work. The where is in the context of Practice. self refers to Practice in instance_eval, so it is like saying self.where, which is Practice, yet it thought it was Main. That's the confusing part.

Comment: No, blocks are lexically scoped, so `self` is whatever it was at the definition site of the block. You can change what `self` is in the block using `instance_eval`, but you are not evaling the block on line 1, you are evaling the block you passed to `instance_eval`.

Comment: To clarify: `instance_eval` changes `self` inside the block passed to `instance_eval`. It does not change `self` in some other block in some other part of the program. That would mean chaos.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get it to work is by passing a parameter to the proc:

```
@collection = model.send query_conditions.collect {|proc| proc.call model }

Proc.new { |model| model.where("#{key} >= #{value[condition]} AND #{key} <= #{value[condition]}") }
```